# Angular - How to concatenate bindLabel in ng-select

Tags: angular

In Angular-12 I am implementing ng-select for the dropdown:

component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
loadAllParameters() {
  this.employeeService.getEmployeeParameters().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.employees = data.results.employees;
    },
    error => {
      this.store.dispatch(loadErrorMessagesSuccess(error));
    }
  );
}
```

this.employees gives:

> id, first_name, last_name

I want to concatenat

> first_name and last_name as bindLabel

and use

> id as bindValue

When I tried this in the HTML:

```
<ng-select [items]="employees"
 [selectOnTab]="true"
 [searchable]="true"
 bindValue="id"
 bindLabel="first_name + ':' + last_name"
 placeholder="Select Employee"
 [multiple]="false"
 [clearable]="true"
 required
 formControlName="id">
</ng-select>
```

I ng-select is not displaying anything. You can see that there are data there, but not visible.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make a map before moving to ng-select. In your file ts, make a map of array.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
loadAllParameters() {
  this.employeeService.getEmployeeParameters().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.employees = data.results.employees;
      this.employees.map(e => {
          e.nameFull = `${e.first_name} ${last_name}`;
      }); //Add map in here.
    },
    error => {
      this.store.dispatch(loadErrorMessagesSuccess(error));
    }
  );
}
```

And ng-select

```
<ng-select [items]="employees"
 [selectOnTab]="true"
 [searchable]="true"
 bindValue="id"
 bindLabel="fullName"
 placeholder="Select Employee"
 [multiple]="false"
 [clearable]="true"
 required
 formControlName="id">
</ng-select>
```

Comment: Where do I out this   employees.map(e => {
    e.nameFull = `${e.first_name} ${last_name}`;
});

Comment: You can right after it you get the data from the employeeService - In ngOnInit

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something similar to this:

```html
<ng-select>
  <ng-option *ngFor="let employee of employees" [value]="id">
    {{ first_name }} : {{ last_name }}
  </ng-option>
</ng-select>
```